# When I make a download by webdriver, I get a "Fail - Download error"

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, download, webdriver

When I make a download by webdriver, I get a "Fail - Download error", but, manually (in a browser without webdriver) I get to make a download normally.

What kind of problem can be ?

The action that invoke the donwload is simply a click in the button, nothing special.

Below, My instance of `ChromeDriver();`

```
  var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                        if (SilentMode)
                        {
                            chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless", "disable-gpu", "silent-launch", "no-startup-window", "incognito");
                        }
                        chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-web-security", "disable-popup-blocking", "AcceptInsecureCertificates", "auth-server-whitelist=*", "no-sandbox", "disable-notifications", "disable-single-click-autofill");
                        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", CaminhoDownload);
                        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
                        Driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
                        NomeProcessoDriver = "chromedriver";
```

Comment: you sure "CaminhoDownload" is the correct path and has permissions set right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your download path. Changing `\_Results\somefolder/` to `/_Results/somefolder/` worked for me.